# How to transform an Excel table to another format

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel Table:

[image]

I would like to transform it into another Table with only 3 columns: the first one with A,B,...C,D,A,B,...,D,..., the second one with 1,2,...,10, and the third one with the corresponding value in the above table.

For example:

- The first line would have the cells A - 1 - 30
- The second line would have the cells A - 2 - 78
- ...
- The last line would have the cells H - 10 - 102

Obviously this can be done manually, but I need a faster way to achieve it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: No, I have not. Would you mind elaborating a bit please?

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1172-excel-transpose-multiple-columns-into-one-column.html

Comment: Are you using Excel 2013/2016? you can use PowerQuery to unpivot data, so that all A-H columns will convert to one column, keeping corespondent values to each row.  [HowToUnpivot](http://www.exceltactics.com/how-to-unpivot-columns-into-rows-in-excel-using-power-query/2/#Unpivot-the-Data-in-Power-Query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Cell K1` enter the following formula

```
=INDEX($B$1:$I$1,1,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/ROWS($A$2:$A$11)))
```

then in `Cell L1` enter

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MOD(ROW(A1)-1+ROWS($A$2:$A$11),ROWS($A$2:$A$11))+1,1)
```

finally, in `Cell M1` enter

```
=INDEX($B$2:$I$11,MOD(ROW(A1)-1+ROWS($A$2:$A$11),ROWS($A$2:$A$11))+1,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/ROWS($A$2:$A$11)))
```

Drag/Copy down above formulas as required. See image for reference.

[image]